# Terraform EMR aws_emr_instance_fleet cluster deletion and recreation

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-emr

I'm creating an EMR cluster with Terraform now and I've gotten the primary/core node fleets up and running without a problem, so I decided to add in a aws_emr_instance_fleet as a Task fleet. Deploying this also worked fine.

The problem is that I then changed some configuration details on the main EMR cluster which resulted in a deletion & recreation of my cluster. According to Terraform documentation:

> At this time, Instance Fleets cannot be destroyed through the API nor web interface. Instance Fleets are destroyed when the EMR Cluster is destroyed. Terraform will resize any Instance Fleet to zero when destroying the resource.

I take this to mean that AWS is in control of the fleet and when the cluster gets the message to delete itself, AWS will then go ahead and delete the fleets associated with it. The problem I realized after doing a delete/recreate is that Terraform seems to be unable to delete or update it's state associated with the fleet. The end result is that I can't successfully complete the EMR deployment. I receive the following error:

```
Error: deleting EMR Instance Fleet (if-ABCDEFG123456): InvalidRequestException: A job flow that is shutting down, terminated, or finished may not be modified.

{

  RespMetadata: {

    StatusCode: 400,

    RequestID: "88q10f23-3b9b-bd62-aaf8-5c35cb5132ba"

  },

  ErrorCode: "INVALID_JOB_SHUT_DOWN",

  Message_: "A job flow that is shutting down, terminated, or finished may not be modified."

}
```

I'm not sure how to address this issue as in my company I do not have write permissions in the AWS console, and checking the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/index.html) I confirm what the Terraform documentation mentioned that there is no way to delete this through the API.

I'm just confused on how this terraform resource should be used. Should it not be used? How do people create task nodes for their EMR cluster with terraform if this isn't the way to go? If it is the way to go (using terraform) where am I going wrong?

It doesn't feel viable to me to break the terraform state if the cluster needs to be recreated.

**EDIT**
The terraform plan command returns this for the plan, showing it is going to need to switch the cluster-id associated w/ the task fleet and the task fleet will end up with a new ID

```
# aws_emr_instance_fleet.task must be replaced

-/+ resource "aws_emr_instance_fleet" "task" {

      ~ cluster_id                     = "j-AAAAAAAAAAAAA" -> "j-BBBBBBBBBBBB" # forces replacement

      ~ id                             = "if-AAAAAAAAAAAAA" -> (known after apply)

        name                           = "my-task-fleet"

      ~ provisioned_on_demand_capacity = 0 -> (known after apply)

      ~ provisioned_spot_capacity      = 0 -> (known after apply)

        # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)



      - instance_type_configs {

          - bid_price_as_percentage_of_on_demand_price = 100 -> null

          - instance_type                              = "m5a.xlarge" -> null

          - weighted_capacity                          = 1 -> null



          - ebs_config {

              - iops                 = 0 -> null

              - size                 = 10 -> null

              - type                 = "gp3" -> null

              - volumes_per_instance = 1 -> null

            }

        }

      + instance_type_configs {

          + bid_price_as_percentage_of_on_demand_price = 100

          + instance_type                              = "m5a.xlarge"

          + weighted_capacity                          = 1



          + ebs_config {

              + size                 = 10

              + type                 = "gp3"

              + volumes_per_instance = 1

            }

        }

    }
```